How do I create a GCE VM with an external IP using Deployment Manager?
I'm trying to use Google Cloud Deployment Manager to create a GCE VM instance with an external ephemeral IP address when network is set to something other than "default".
What I mean by the latter point is that if network is set to https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[MY_PROJECT]/global/networks/default as suggested in the Getting Started example (https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/manage-cloud-resources-deployment), it creates the instance with an external ephemeral IP address.
However, I want to explicitly set network to another VPC that I create with:
- type: compute.v1.network
  name: my-vpc
  properties:
    autoCreateSubnetworks: true

The documentation states:

accessConfigs.natIP: Specify an unused static external IP address available to the project or leave this field undefined to use an IP from a shared ephemeral IP address pool.

I've tried leaving the field undefined in a number of ways but it still doesn't provision the VM with an ephemeral external IP.
I've tried:
networkInterfaces:
- network: $(ref.my-vpc.selfLink)
accessConfigs:
  - name: External NAT
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT

networkInterfaces:
- network: $(ref.my-vpc.selfLink)
accessConfigs:
  - name: External NAT
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
    natIP: 

networkInterfaces:
- network: $(ref.my-vpc.selfLink)
accessConfigs:
  - name: External NAT
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
    natIP: ~

networkInterfaces:
- network: $(ref.my-vpc.selfLink)
accessConfigs:
  - name: External NAT
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
    natIP: null

I've look at the other resources types like network and firewall to see if there are any options there that would result in an external IP being assigned but it doesn't seem like it. I'd appreciate any help on this.
Thanks!
SOLVED: It was a YAML indentation issue. :( Needed to change it to this:
networkInterfaces:
- network: $(ref.my-vpc.selfLink)
  accessConfigs:
  - name: External NAT
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT


It's been a minute since I used Deployment Manager. I think (!) you need name and perhaos networkTier for a valid accessConfigs, type defaults to ONE_TO_ONE_NAT. I just tried a simple repro and with only name, the VM was bound to an ephemeral external IP.

I figured it out. YAML indentation issue. :(
Since I can't do formatting in a comment, I'll update the post.
